# memset() function outputs undesirably

Tags: c++

Here is the screenshot of my problem.

[image]

The code is

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

int a[6][500], b[6][500];

int main()
{
    memset (a,  3, sizeof a);
    memset (b, -1, sizeof b);
    cout << a[2][50] << ' ' << b[2][50] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I don't understand why a[2][500] is showing 50529027. Can anyone tell me what's the difference between the two memset() call ?

Comment: You might have better luck using something like `std::fill`.

Comment: @dreamlax although it's not straightfoward: need `std::fill( (int *)a, (int *)(&a + 1), 3 );`

Comment: Or `(&a[0][0], &a[6][0], 3)` for those who dislike casts.

Answer (score 2):

`memset()` is in byte. `a` is `int`, so `a[2][500]` on 32 bit machine, value is 0x03030303 = 50529027

Answer (score 2):

50529037 is 0x03030303.  `memset()` sets memory by byte value.

Answer (score 0):

`memset(`) works byte by byte which includes **0, 1, -1, false, true** only.

Reference: [GeeksForGeeks](http://geeksforgeeks.org/memset-in-cpp/amp/)